# Not getting expected pixel height when testing with Nightwatch

Tags: javascript, css, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, nightwatch.js

First of all, in case anybody asks for my machine info:

- CentOS 7
- kmod-nvidia Graphics drivers (dedicated GPU)

I have a webpage that I am testing with Nightwatch, and one of the criteria is making sure a background image's height is the height that is is supposed to be.

To summarize the problem I'm having:  I need to verify that the background image (or containing div) is height: calc(90vh - 200). I have either been getting greatly differing values, slightly different, or unknown/null values. Firefox is the only browser to have actually been spot on.

**Below is some data that I have collected in my trouble shooting, and it is laid out as follows:**

- Rendering Browser: Which browser Nightwatch uses to render the page to test
- Window.innerHeight: The viewport that the height attribute uses to calculate the expected height
- Computed Value: What the height should be (innerHeight x 0.9 - 200)
- Test Expected: The expected value in the Nightwatch test.

  - The test: client.verify.cssProperty("div.Background", "height", data.value.height);
  - Data is the variable where I have put my computed (expected) height from a client.execute() function.
- Test Actual: The actual rendered value reported by nightwatch.

  1. NIghtwatch's default browser (PhantomJS)

     - vp = 1080
     - Computed (height) = 772
     - Expected = 772
     - Actual = 600
  2. Chrome

     - vp = 967
     - computed = 670.3
     - Expected = 670.300000001
     - Actual = 670.297
  3. Firefox

     - vp = 945
     - Computed = 650.5
     - Expected = 650.5
     - Actual = 650.5
  4. We also have our implementation of Nightwatch spin off a custom hosted port separate from selenium.  I have seen this value to be different from the above, but I just checked today as I'm writting this (on my local chrome browser), and It was behaving the same as PhantomJS, although with some variances.

Additionally, in the client.execute() function, I also attempted to retrieve this information from the DOM itself, but whenever I try any iteration of an element height, it gives me "unknown".

Here is an example of some code I'm using for various things in my above explanation:

```
client.resizeWindow(1920, 1080);
client.waitForElementVisible("background", 3000); // passes
client.execute(function(){ return window.innerHeight; }, [], (result) => {
  console.log("viewport:" + JSON.stringify(result.value));
}
client.getElementSize("div.background", (elementSize) => { //outputs wrong value
   console.log("elementSize: " + elementSize.value.height);
});

client.execute(function() {
  var data = {};
  var el = document.getElementsByClassName("background").clientHeight; //insert any height function here
  data.height = ((0.9 * window.innerHeight) - 200); //this is what it should be
  data.elementHeight = "height: " + el + "px";
  return data;
}, [], (data) => {
  console.log("computed Height: " + data.value.height);
  console.log("element height: " + data.value.elementHeight); //this gives "unknown"

  client.verify.cssProperty("div.background", height, data.value.height);
})
```

Additionally, I have been having some problems with my graphics driver recently, and thought this might be the issue, but I have since ruled this out today.

Thanks in advance for any feedback, or thoughts on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the minute differences in chrome are probably within a margin of error in whatever calculation algorithm they use (correct me if I'm wrong).  Otherwise I realized my major issue was with the Phantom.js browser that Nightwatch.js uses.

More specifically I noticed when making a mock html page in plunker, that the calc function had some issues with divs with a background image of which calc was setting the height to. If I removed the calc() function, then the image loaded once again.

Ex. Html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="doTheThing"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Ex. Css:

```
.doTheThing: {
  background-image: url('insertRandomImageUrlHere');
  height: calc(90vh - 200); //didn't work.  Image didn't load
  height: 90vh; //worked, image loaded.
}
```

Scratching my head at this odd behavior I thought about it some more and looked specifically into the rendering browser Phantom.js with this regard and I came across this issue here: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/13547

By the looks of it, it is entirely possible that calc() is being computed incorrectly by Phantom.js and this is causing the difference in pixels.  (also note, that the 600px in the above tests in my original post would be because there is a min-height of 600 set, so the computed value would've been less than 600.)

I believe this solves this issue, however I believe it warrants another question specifically to phantom.js to see if the situation has updated.  I'll also update my answer if I find otherwise conflicting conclusions to this answer.

I'll note my new question bellow once it's made.

[Phantomjs browser incorrectly computing css calc() function in Nightwatch tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47722907/phantomjs-browser-incorrectly-computing-css-calc-function-in-nightwatch-tests)